# Miniziming convex quadratic function over unit simplex — is there a closed form solution?

Tags: optimization, convex-optimization, quadratic-programming

Given matrix $A \in \mathbb{R}^{3\times 4}$ and vector $b \in \mathbb{R}^3$, I have the following optimization problem in $w \in \mathbb{R}^4$

\begin{equation*}
\min_{w \in \Delta}\frac{1}{2}\lVert Aw - b\rVert_2^2
\end{equation*}

where

$$\Delta := \left\{ w \in \mathbb{R}^4 \mid w \geq 0, \sum_{i=1}^4 w_i = 1 \right\}$$

Could you please help me solve this problem? Is there a closed form solution to this problem?

---

**Motivation**

This optimization problem arises as a part of computer vision pipeline and is mainly used to perform co-ordinate transformation. I am trying to process as many frames per second as possible. Having a closed form solution instead of a numerical one would reduce the computation time significantly, in my humble opinion. For more information, see [this](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/4222928) question.

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Quadratic_programming

Comment: @arthur, I found [this](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/88746/convex-minimization-over-the-unit-simplex). Since my function is convex and twice differentiable, I guess, I could use the exponential gradient method.

Comment: @mechatron Are you acquainted with [CVXGEN](https://cvxgen.com)? If not, [this](https://youtu.be/uhGMnT12zOg) talk may interest you.

Comment: @RodrigodeAzevedo, I have used CVXPY before. They appear be similar since both are from Professor Boyd's group.

Comment: @mechatron Yes, but CVXGEN produces C code that should run much, much faster than Python.  Perhaps fast enough to solve 100 quadratic programs per second. Would that be fast enough for you?

Comment: @RodrigodeAzevedo, I believe so. I must do some experiments to be certain about this. Thank you. I found the video you linked quite helpful :)

Comment: @RodrigodeAzevedo, of course. I'll edit my answer below to include more information :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Based on what i have read from [here](https://citeseerx.ist.psu.edu/viewdoc/download;jsessionid=1E4CB10EB60AA0DA601EE19D7C8856F5?doi=10.1.1.36.9298&rep=rep1&type=pdf), I end up with the following update rule
\begin{equation*}
(w_{t+1})_i = (w_t)_i \cdot \frac{\exp(-\eta(\nabla_{w_t}f)_i)}{w_t^T\exp(-\eta\nabla_{w_t}f)}, \forall i
\end{equation*}
In my case, $\nabla_{w_t}f = A^T(Aw_t-b)$. Here $\eta > 0$ is the learning rate and $w_0$ can be chosen as $(0.25, 0.25, 0.25, 0.25)$

The stopping condition would be $\lVert w_{t+1} - w_t \rVert_2 \leq \epsilon$ for some $\epsilon > 0$

Answer (score 0):

Just use a non negative least squares solver. For example, [scipy.optimize.nnls](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/generated/scipy.optimize.nnls.html) gives the solution vector back directly if you define the matrix $A$ and vector $b$.
To have $\Delta := \{ w \in \mathbb{R}^4 | w \geq 0, \sum_i w_i = 1 \}$, just normalize the solution vector afterwards as $\frac{w}{\sum_i^n{w_i}}$ or add a regularization part to your function \begin{equation*}
\min_{w \in \Delta}\frac{1}{2}\lVert Aw - b\rVert_2^2
+\lambda||w||_2^2\end{equation*}

Comment: I am unable to understand why your answer might be correct. Could you please help me in this regard ? Why would the set of global minimizers I get from your solution be equal to set of global minimizers for my problem ?

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Non-negative_least_squares

Comment: Domain of $f$ is positive cone in non-negative least squares whereas domain of $f$ is simplex in my case.

Comment: Okay, but I didn't get that from your question. In that case, you can use any numerical algorithm that updates the gradient or the hessian of $w$. Scipy has implemented several of them https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/tutorial/optimize.html

Comment: Also take a look at http://pages.cs.wisc.edu/~brecht/cs838docs/wolfe-qp.pdf

Comment: The last one is frank-wolfe method right ? Thank you for the resources